# Not sure about the swapping mechanics of Insertion Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

```
const insertionSort = arr => {
  const len = arr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    let el = arr[i]; //el = 44
    console.log(el); 
    let j;

    for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && arr[j] > el; j--) { //j=0, 99> 44
      arr[j + 1] = arr[j]; //arr[1] = arr[0] 99 takes the position of 44 in index 1
    }
    arr[j + 1] = el; 
    console.log(arr);
  }
  return arr;
};  

insertionSort([99,44,22])
```

Repl below:

https://repl.it/@Stylebender/insertionSort

In my input of [99,44,22], just wondering in which line of code does 44 take the position of 99 at index 0 because I'm not sure I'm seeing it...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stepping through this with a debugger would do you a world of good.

Answer (score 0):

It's the line of

```
arr[j + 1] = el;
```

`j` is `-1` at the end of the loop, so `j + 1` is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop and the line after is where the swapping takes place:

```
for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && arr[j] > el; j--) {
   arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
}
arr[j + 1] = el;
```

When i=0 nothing happens j = i - 1 = -1 and so the inner loop doesn't execute.

But in the next iteration i=1 so `el` is set to the second element, which is 44. Then j = i - 1 = 0 and `arr[0]` is 99 which is greater than `el` so the inner loop executes. so `arr[1]` is set to `arr[0]` which is 99. Then j is decremented to -1 and now the inner loop stops.

So j+1 = 0 and no `arr[j+1]` or `arr[0]` is set to `el` which is 44. So now 44 and 99 have been swapped.